# Is lightening a form of alternating or direct current?

Tags: electric-current, lightning

Is lightening a form of alternating or direct current? I have no idea about this, so help me.

Answer (score 1):

Lightning is a one-directional strike.  As a [general rule](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/estatics/Lesson-4/Lightning), the bottom of clouds form a negative charge, so when the lightning strikes, electrons flow from the cloud to the ground.

That being said, I would not call it *either* alternating current nor direct current.  Most people who work with AC or DC have assumptions that come with it, and if you call something direct current, it may confuse them.  In this case, the electrons do flow in one direction, as they do in direct current, but they do so in an incredibly short and intense burst, while DC is typically thought of as a rather steady source.

So if this is what you think of when you think of DC:
[image: battery]
Then you probably should be careful thinking about lightning as direct current, even though the electrons only flow one way, because it might confuse you.

On the other hand, if you are comfortable calling [this](https://celnav.de/hv/hv4.htm) one-directional but very ripply arc DC:

[image: DC arc]

Then you can probably get away with calling lightning DC as well.

Comment: Both sparks and lightning create a lot of electromagnetic waves at radiofrequencies. For sparks, there is always some capacitances and inductances that may give oscillations as a transient response to the discharge pulse.  Maybe similar things are happening in clouds too. Or sequences of pulses, the "stepped leader" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Lightning is an electric discharge of very high dc voltages between clouds and the earth or between clouds. Thus lightning is produced by a direct current that heats and ionizes the air molecules along its path.